# VBA “Save to PDF” saves even on cancels

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a problem with a macro. I would like to avoid that the macro saves the PDF file even if I press on *Cancel* in the *Save dialog box*. What did I miss?

Here's the code:

```
Set ws = Foglio5

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(Foglio5.Cells(14, 2) & "_" & (Foglio5.Cells(14, 4) & "_" & (Foglio5.Cells(15, 10))), "", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Foglio5.Cells(17, 5), "yyyymmdd\") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF Creato! Si trova nella cartella di questo file."
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Errore nella creazione del PDF"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

I tried changing:

```
If myFile <> "False" Then
```

into:

```
If myFile Then
```

Now it is not working anymore and it says that it is impossible to save the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

```
myFile <> "False"
```

should be

```
myFile <> False
```

[ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Should probably add that `myFile` should be `Dim`'d as a `Variant` so it can work if `Option Explicit` is used...